# Increase speed of array population when using nested for loops - matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I have written this function to find indices based on certain criteria. It should work, the problem is that it will take 2-3 days to run on my pc. Is there any way to get it down below an hour (or faster at all) ? This really doesn't need to be very fast. But 2 days is unacceptably slow.

I don't expect an in depth analysis on the function (Though it would be nice). Just some general improvements.

All it essentially is is 3 for-loops used to populate 8 large 3d arrays using another 256x8 matrix Logic. Then a few logic tests to find the desired index.

```
%These are sample values from the g.u.i. and other functions - 
%ignore up til the loops unless you need it to understand something in the loops.

PriceMat=[58867 55620 16682 97384 11660 18175 25896 16300];
CapMat=[1400 1200 450 3600 150 1330 2000 250];
RepMat=[58 53 31 127 15 164 242 27];
DesiredRep=293.04;
DesiredCap=2600;

prevmin=99999999;
P=perms(0:7);

D=zeros(256,8,40320);
Cap=zeros(size(D,3),8);
Rep=zeros(size(D,3),8);
Price=zeros(size(D,3),8);
SufRep=zeros(1,size(D,3));
SufCap=zeros(1,size(D,3));
CapTot=zeros(1,size(D,3));
RepTot=zeros(1,size(D,3));
PriceTot=zeros(1,size(D,3));


for i=1:40320
    for x=1:8

        for   j=1:256
            D(j,x,i)=P(i,x)*Logic(j,x);

            Cap(i,x)=D(j,x,i)*CapMat(x);
            Price(i,x)=D(j,x,i)*PriceMat(x);
            Rep(i,x)=D(j,x,i)*RepMat(x);
            CapTot=sum(Cap,2);
            RepTot=sum(Rep,2);
            PriceTot=sum(Price,2);

            if CapTot(i)>=DesiredCap
                SufCap(i)=true;
            else 
                SufCap(i)=false;
            end

            if RepTot(i)>=DesiredRep
                SufRep(i)=true;
            else 
                SufRep(i)=false;
            end

            if SufRep(i)==true && SufCap(i)==true

                if PriceTot(i)<=prevmin
                    prevmin=i;
                end
            end

        end

    end

end

return prevmin
```

Comment: What is `Logic(j,x)`?

Comment: Logic is another array. The 256 by 8 matrix I mentioned at the start is Logic, not D. Sorry about that. Will edit it now

Comment: what is `D(j,x)`? `D` is 3D...

Comment: Should be D(j,x,i). Copied from a previous attempt earlier and didn't notice that, thanks.

Comment: Can you please update your code so all "known bugs" are out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said "it would be nice" to get some in depth analysis of your function. It's pretty complex -and can be greatly simplified. I am a little bit worried about the amount of memory that my solution would take - one of your 256x8x40320 arrays is about 660 MB, and I create four. If that's not a problem, great. Otherwise you might have to choose a more conservative data type to keep memory requirements down - if you start swapping to disk you are dead, timing wise.

So let's assume you are not limited by RAM, then the following will speed things up considerably (note - I am stealing Shai's suggestion to use bsxfun). Note also that I am clearing the "really big" arrays after taking their sum - this could all be done in one line but it would be even harder for you to follow:

```
D = bsxfun( @times, permute( P, [ 3 2 1] ), Logic );
Cap = bsxfun( @times, D, CapMat );
CapTot = sum( Cap, 2 );
clear Cap

Price = bsxfun( @times, PriceMat );
PriceTot = sum( Price, 2 );
clear Price

Rep = bsxfun( @times, D, RepMat ); % <<<<< STRONGLY recommend not to use RepMat -
                                   % <<<<< to avoid confusion with built in repmat()
RepTot = sum( Rep, 2 );
clear Rep

CapRepOK = ( CapTot >= DesiredCap && RepTot >= DesiredRep ); % logical array - fast, small

[minPrice minPriceInd ] = min(PriceTot(CapRepOK)); % find minimum value and index

% convert index to correct value of `i` in original code:
cs = cumsum(ok(:)); % increases by one for every value that meets criteria
                    % but we need to know which original index that corresponds to:
possibleValues = find( cs == minPriceInd );
[j i] = ind2sub( size(CapRepOK), possibleValues(1) );
prevmin = i;
```

Obviously I don't have your data so it's a bit hard to be sure this replicates your functionality exactly - but I believe it does. If not - that's what comments are for.

I suspect it is possible never to create the largest arrays (D etc) with some careful thought - if you are truly memory starved that may be needed.

Comment: Unfortunately memory is quite a big problem. Im running a 32bit with 4GB RAM  - . The maximum array size my pc can handle is about 700-1200MB. Total Memory available for all arrays is roughly 1500-1700MB with everything I know of done to free up memory. I could run it on a colleague's better PC I suppose. Thank you very much for your effort, will definitely try some of your proposals and experiment with bsxfun.

Comment: For many applications it is sufficient to use `float` as the data type - it depends a bit on the range of values and the required accuracy. If so, then making `P`, `Logic`, `CapMat`, `PriceMat` and `RepMat` `float` from the outset will halve the memory requirement and may well give a speed boost.

Answer (score 1):

use `bsxfun` it's so much FUN!

Here's how you can compute matrix `D` in a single line (no loops):

```
 D = bsxfun( @times, permute( P, [3 2 1] ), Logic );
```

I guess you can take it from here and compute the rest of the matrices this way - no loops.

Comment: I didn't realize you could `permute` a 2D matrix into a 3D one with the trick you used - that is classy. I don't think you want `Logic` to be transposed though... order of its dimensions is `(j,x)` same as for `D`

Comment: @Floris check out the [tag:bsxfun] tag wiki for more nice tips and tricks.